# Is it normal for ABE to get "out of sync" whilst re-creating it's blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, abe

Is it normal for [ABE](https://github.com/jtobey/bitcoin-abe/blob/master/README.md#welcome-to-abe) to get "out of sync" whilst re-creating it's blockchain?

I am concerned that the number on the left does not match the number on the right. I have no idea what those two numbers are, I just know that the examples show them both being the same thing, and that they did indeed start out being the same:

```
 block_tx 1 1
 block_tx 2 2
 block_tx 3 3
```

Here's what it looks like now:

[image: ABE output.]

This process has been running for a number of hours now, and is only getting further and further "out of sync" with the original number as it does so.

Just curious if I should stop it now and start over?

Comment: Maybe you can add a link to what ABE is...

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure I can answer my own question here... the output is literally the total number of blocks, and the total number of transactions witnessed by ABE posted side by side.

Everything seems to be running smoothly. The number of transactions is increasing almost exponentially now by the number of blocks.

Comment: And the numbers matched at first because the first 170 blocks in the chain had only one transaction each.